# Execute function after FragmentManager commit

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a toolbar with text that is updated after an item in my menu is selected.

The problem is that I call the function that handles the title in my toolbar right after my transaction like this:

```java
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
setTitle()
```

However, when my function is called, the Fragment I get is always the one currently displayed and not the new one.

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments.last()
```

I'm guessing the Fragments transaction takes place in a Thread. How do I wait until it's complete to perform my function?

Comment: if you don't need a backstack you can use `commitNow` to perform transaction synchronously

Comment: I'm using a backstack with addToBackStack(null)

Comment: is the toolbar in activity (which contains the fragment container) ?

Comment: @Darshn Yes the Toolbar is in the main Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not adding your fragment to the back stack you cannot use the built-in [`FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html) so instead you can either call 
[`executePendingTransactions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#executependingtransactions) right after you commit the transaction or use `commitNow()` method instead of `commit()` to do the same, then handle your toolbar changes with `setTitle()`.

Comment: I'm actually adding my Fragment to the back stack

Comment: In that case you can easily use the listener which gets called after each transaction is made (pop or push). Just be careful of the back stack tag you're using which must be unique for each item of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using KTX extensions you can wait for fragment to be created using [`LifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) instead of listening to fragment manager directly.

First ensure you have `fragment-ktx` dependency in your app level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.1'
    ...
}
```

Then you can perform a suspended execution that waits for your fragment to be created:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
fragment.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated { 
    setTitle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i respond to your question so late but it could help someone who want the same solution :

```
fragment.getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
                     @Override
                     public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source, @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
                         if(event.getTargetState() == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){
                             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                    setTitle();
                                 }
                             }, 500);
                         }
                     }
                 });
```